QGIS Python Get and layout item's Uuid
I am working on synchronising the view extents of maps on layouts.
I can do this using .layoutByName, .itemById, .extent and then .setExtent to get the Map I want from the right layout then find its extents and apply those to another map on a different layout.
Currently I am getting the items using .layoutByName but as my layout names are going to change that won't work. I think I should be able to get the layouts by their Uuid but I can't figure out how.
Currently my Code is something like the code below
Surveylayout_name = '24888-TRS-02' !!!This name will change!!
SurveyMap_name = 'Tree_Survey_Map'

#getting the layout details for the source plan
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
sourcelayout = manager.layoutByName('24888-CON-01')
get_sourceMap = sourcelayout.itemById('Constraints_A')
get_sourcemap_extents = get_get_sourceMap.extent()


#getting the target plan 
Target_layout = manager.layoutByName('24888-TRS-02')
get_TargetMap = Target_layout.itemById('Tree_Survey_Map')
get_TargetMap.setExtent(get_sourcemap_extents)  


I don't think layouts do have a uuid. The layout manager can return a list of layouts, could you use the index of that list to target them? E.g. manager.printLayouts()[0]. The list should be in the order in which they have been added. Admittedly it's a bit awkward if you need to remove layouts, or if you have lots of them.

@SirLostalot targeting using layout index works fine, I don't have many layouts that need syncing so its workable.

Super, happy for me to add this as an answer then?

To do it safely you can try selecting index by a .index() method of the list, e.g. layoutlist.index('24888-CON-01')

@SirLostalot you have my permission to answer the question,

Layouts do not have a uuid. The layout manager can return a list of layouts, so you can use the index of that list to target them instead E.g.:
manager.printLayouts()[0]. 

The list should be in the order in which they have been added.
